# DrawItem in listbox (VC++)

Tags: visual-c++

When we will use DrawItem for a listbox?
Normally, if the listbox is ownerdraw, we will use DrawItem. What are the other senarios we use drawitem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on Rashmi Pandit; A ListBox with override DrawItem can also be used to 'visualize' objects. In a project I'm working on, a ListBox is used to display rows from a database. Each row / item is visualized using formatted Strings, Icons etc.

Overriding DrawItem (and MeasureItem!) is ideal for this purpose. Of course, the internal structure has to be tweaked a bit (the standard Items property cannot be used for objects), but it is certainly worthwhile.

Comment: I just saw you're using VC++. I'm using Delphi. However, the philosophy is probably very much the same

Answer (score 0):

Message WM_DRAWITEM is sent only to owner-drawn List boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DrawItem when you want to override the default implementation and custom the way a listbox is drawn. For e.g. in the list there might be some item which should is the default item and you would want it to be highlighted so that the user knows it is the default item.

Here's an eg for a combo in C#: [Higlighting a particular item in a combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856397/higlighting-a-particular-item-in-a-combo-box)