# ComboBox with Segoe UI and Japanese text

Tags: winforms, unicode, fonts, combobox, cleartype

I’m currently trying to make my C# application look better when run within Windows Vista or Windows 7. By default, Windows Forms applications use the *Microsoft Sans Serif* font, which does not link properly to Asian clear type fonts such as *Meiryo*.

To fix this issue, I set all the fonts to *Segoe UI* (or `SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont`) instead. This works quite well for most of Controls, but I noticed it causes weird display glitches with at least the `ComboBox` control:

[image: Example]

The `ComboBox` fails to display this list correctly. Characters get cropped oddly and the selected item looks like it requires more space than originally reserved.

Is there any solution or workaround to this behaviour?

In case you want to try it for yourself, here's my list of items:

- テスト
- てすと
- 実験

Thanks!

Comment: I've had good luck with 'Arial Unicode MS' when displaying Japanese and Chinese characters.

Answer (score 2):

I repro on Win7.  Something is borked in the font mapper by the looks of it, the substitute font is clearly too large.  Notable is the problem does *not* occur with Microsoft Sans Serif.  And it maps just fine on my machine.

Tough to give cheap advice here, you really need the help from Microsoft Support.  You also ought to check it on the Japanese version of Windows, odds are decent that it will have fonts that don't require mapping.

Comment: Hmm, seems impossible to report this to Microsoft. The Microsoft Support website wants to charge me like $400 for a single question...

Comment: Yes, you'll get your money back when they find out it is their bug.  That is not impossible.  You also really need that Japanese version of Windows, don't ship without testing on it.  An MSDN subscription is the best way to get it, the subscription also includes two free support cases.

Comment: I'm still a student, so my apps have no commercial purpose and I can't afford the MSDN subscription. I wonder if there’s really no workaround to overcome this issue?

Comment: Well, if this is actually a problem on a Japanese machine then I'm sure they'll be happy to overlook the minor flaw.

Comment: I'm not sure why a "Japanese version of Windows" is relevant. It's quite valid and feasible that the questioner is developing a Japanese language dictionary for English students of the Japanese language.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (but with some other characters and font) not sure if it will work for you but it is quite simple to implement the DrawItem event and draw the text yourself.

We use a method similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/857232/417721