# Greek character are not displayed in winform combobox

Tags: winforms, unicode, datagrid, .net-2.0

I am working on a winform application, where I have grid with column displaying certain length measurement units. I have defined a column as below.

```
var unitColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn {
    Name = "UnitColumn",
    HeaderText = "UnitColumnHeader",
    Width = 80,
    DataSource = new[] { "nm", "mm", "μm" },
};
_calibGrid.Columns.Add(unitColumn);
```

As you can see the second item in the combobox suppose to display `μm`, but it displays the `m`. After I choose the item text in the cell displayed correctly. I am quite new to winform development, can any one suggest the fix/solution?

[image]

Comment: Be sure that the font you are using can display those characters. verify - `Start + Run` > _charmap_ > OK. try this - `Console.WriteLine("\u00b5");`

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal `\u00b5` worked for me. I used `\u00b5m` instead of `µm`

Comment: Brr, *very* mysterious problem.  Try another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Try - Console.WriteLine("\u00b5");`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same problem (but with some other characters). Don't know why it does this.

It is quite simple to implement the DrawItem event and draw the text correctly. We use a method similar to this:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/857232/417721